# How can i listen for Fragment change in my Activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have an Activity which based on intent opens Fragment1 or Fragment2.

From the activity after some stuff are done if the user is in Fragment1 i replace the fragment to Fragment2 and that can be done even from the Fragment1 diretly.

For each Fragment i have to change items in my BottomAppBar, till i'm in Activity i have no problems with it as i've made just a function which changes the bottomAppBar items based on value passed it in.

The issue is when the `.replace` is called directly from the fragment.

So i tought if it was possible to set in anyway a 'FragmentListener' which listens for fragment change in my Activity and call that function from it..

My function looks like this:

```
private fun changeBottomBar(corpo: Boolean = false) {
    if (corpo) {
        binding.bottomAppBar.navigationIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            this,
            R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24
        )
        binding.bottomAppBar.menu.findItem(R.id.filter).isVisible = false
        binding.bottomSheetTestata.titleBottomSheet.text = "Modifica Documento"
        bottomSheetTestataBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        binding.bottomAppBar.menu.findItem(R.id.testata).isVisible = tipo != "Etichette"
    }else {
        binding.bottomAppBar.navigationIcon = null
        binding.bottomAppBar.menu?.findItem(R.id.testata)?.isVisible = false
        binding.bottomAppBar.menu?.findItem(R.id.filter)?.isVisible = true
        binding.bottomSheetTestata.titleBottomSheet.text = "Nuovo Documento"
        clearTestata()
        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
    }
}
```

And i call it for every `.replace` where if the Fragment is Fragment2 i pass to it `corpo = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EventBus Open source library for subscribing and publishing events.

https://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

For Publishing Event

```
 //In fragment
 EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

For Subscribing Event in Activity

```
//In Activity
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Define you custom model class for event

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

Comment: Hi Ranjeet, i would prevent the usage of external libraries

Comment: Hi @NiceToMytyuk then use interfaces to listen in between fragments and activities